# Use a list with specific sample size by group in R and apply it to the dataset

Tags: r, list, sample

I have a lookup file that looks like this

```
id   department     sample_size
1    accounting     2
2    finance        3
```

And I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
id  name     gender    salary_in_K department
1   john     M         $60         accounting
2   karina   F         $45         accounting
3   angela   F         $70         accounting
4   mike     M         $40         accounting
5   ken      M         $25         accounting
6   fin      M         $37         finance
7   riley    F         $58         finance
8   joe      M         $61         finance
9   dre      M         $32         finance
10  kelly    F         $85         finance
11  lisa     F         $33         finance
```

So the output I'd expect would be 5 rows that randomly came from df, 2 of which came from accounting and 3 of which came from finance.

The output would have all the columns from the dataframe but with only 5 rows

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can join `df1` (lookup table) with `df2` by `'department'` and for each `department` select randomly `sample_size` rows.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = 'department') %>%
  group_by(department) %>%
  sample_n(first(sample_size)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(department, id = id.y, name:salary_in_K)

# department    id name   gender salary_in_K
#  <chr>      <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>      
#1 accounting     2 karina F      $45        
#2 accounting     1 john   M      $60        
#3 finance        8 joe    M      $61        
#4 finance       10 kelly  F      $85        
#5 finance        9 dre    M      $32
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse solution, using `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `purrr`. Assuming that your lookup data frame is `df1` and the data is in `df2`.

We store the data for each department in a column `data` using `nest()`. Then join with the lookup data, and use `pmap()` to supply the correct arguments to `sample_n()`, storing the sampled data in `sampled`. Finally we select `department` and `sampled` and `unnest()` to get the sampled data back into rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

set.seed(1001) # for reproducibility

df2 %>% 
  nest(data = -department) %>% 
  left_join(df1) %>% 
  mutate(sampled = pmap(list(data, sample_size), sample_n)) %>% 
  select(department, sampled) %>% 
  unnest(cols = sampled)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  department    id name   gender salary_in_K
  <chr>      <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>      
1 accounting     3 angela F      $70        
2 accounting     5 ken    M      $25        
3 finance        8 joe    M      $61        
4 finance        9 dre    M      $32        
5 finance       10 kelly  F      $85
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` solution, with `df1` being your lookup table, from which we can generate a named vector, and `df2` being the main data.frame:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df2) # convert to data.table
df1 <- with(df1, setNames(sample_size, department)) # named lookup vector

set.seed(1001)
df2[, .SD[sample(.N, df1[.GRP])], keyby = department]
#>    department id   name gender salary_in_K
#> 1: accounting  3 angela      F         $70
#> 2: accounting  5    ken      M         $25
#> 3:    finance  8    joe      M         $61
#> 4:    finance  9    dre      M         $32
#> 5:    finance 10  kelly      F         $85
```